# Site not loading,DNS not working

Tags: redirect, dns, hosting, rackspace

As i am trying to open my site(posting.ly) but its not working rather it shows blank page for a while than error of "could not load posting.ly"

I have updated the namespace and tested it,updated A recoord,but cannot figure out the problem.I have already worked with DNS and i know this should work plus its more than 24 hrs so this should work or show me a proper error.

Hosting is rackspace and i have added A record of the ip address.

Comment: Have you got index in website directory? Is the DNS really ok? You can check it via `dig` command (in Linux or iOS) and you will see, what DNS is currently active

Comment: Thanks for replying,I really don't have any idea of this but i tried itand got 13 answer to it,this is what i get! [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xhcbe8qrqblwo8/dgi.png

Comment: In answer section you can see actual NS records for that domain. Are these URL's correct? I mean ... is root-servers.net the server, what you wanna point to?

Comment: I don't get it,here is the link to domain DNS record :https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggca51mwsv18pxl/p2.png

Comment: And this is the link to my hosting DNS details:https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z9bpuk9wn2fszx/posting.ly.png

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fine now.  No www or wildcard, but main domain resolves.

```
$ checksoa posting.ly

 Serial #           RTT(ms)      Nameservers (name, IP, SOA mname field) for posting.ly

1403808455     50              dns1.stabletransit.com    69.20.95.4           SOA: ns.rackspace.com
1403808455     80              dns2.stabletransit.com    65.61.188.4         SOA: ns.rackspace.com

$ dig +noall +answer +authority posting.ly
posting.ly.             300     IN      A       162.13.143.172

$ dig +noall +answer +authority www.posting.ly
posting.ly.             300     IN      SOA     ns.rackspace.com. azm.dar.gmail.com. 1403808455 21600 3600 1814400 300
```